# What's the difference between /authorize and /login endpoints in AWS Cognito User Pools

Tags: amazon-cognito

From AWS docs,

AUTHORIZATION Endpoint
The /oauth2/authorize endpoint signs the user in.

GET /oauth2/authorize
The /oauth2/authorize endpoint only supports HTTPS GET. The user pool client typically makes this request through the system browser, which would typically be Custom Chrome Tab in Android and Safari View Control in iOS.

LOGIN Endpoint
The /login endpoint signs the user in. It loads the login page and presents the authentication options configured for the client to the user.

GET /login
The /login endpoint only supports HTTPS GET. The user pool client makes this request through the system browser, which would typically be Custom Chrome Tabs in Android and Safari View Controller in iOS.

Both endpoints redirect after success, which one to use when?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference I noticed is if you have only one identity provider enabled the /authorize route will skip the hosted UI. The identity provider must be a Federation one for this to work. If the identity provider is Cognito you'll still be redirected to the hosted UI to type your password.

Comment: Thanks @Hugodby, that looks like an observed one, rather then a defined one